# .Net Mvc5 Basic Script Example

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to add a Html part in to my webpage after Option selection.

```
<select id="EditGorevTuru" multiple class="default" onchange="this.form.submit() ">
        @foreach (var i in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID))
        {
            <option value="@i.ID">@i.GOREVTURADI</option>
        }
</select>
```

After selection I want to add 1 button into my div which is

```
<div id="afterSelection">
</div>
```

I tried but didnot succeed on trying script.(Also I want to take The value of my selection into my script for using it.)

I tried that script just to see if I can see an alert etc

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("EditGorevTuru").on("select", function () {
        $(this).val();
        Alert("selected");
    }

    ), $("afterSelect").html("<h6>ASDF</h6>");
</script>
```

Comment: Can you expand on how your attempt did not succeed - what was the actual vs. expected result?

Comment: I want to make edit after selection. I will create a div id = "afterSelection" In That Div I will create Ajax Beginform . I know how to Use that Ajax.Beginform Part, But I cannot fill div by script.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <select id="EditGorevTuru" multiple="multiple" class="default" onchange="changedFunction()" >
            @foreach (var i in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID))
            {
                <option value="@i.ID">@i.GOREVTURADI</option>
            }
        </select>
<div id="afterSelect"></div>
```

and my function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changedFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("EditGorevTuru").value;
        document.getElementById("afterSelect").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
    }
</script>
```

Now It is working :)) 
In that div I will write an embed Ajax begin form than I will edit selection, Thanks..